# Is it possible to compile AOSP on the Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: android, cross-compilation, pi-4, software-compilation

I am planning to get the RPi4 with 4GB RAM to replace my desktop.
I occasionally build AOSP and Lineage for my android devices, so I wanted to check if RPI4 can be used to compile the same?

I have checked the AOSP docs and it says 64-bit OS is necessary for compilation and a minimum of 4GB RAM and 250GB of storage.
I can live will long build times, but since the doc doesn't say anything about the HOST system's architecture, it got me curious.

Comment: Quick comment.  I vaguely remember someone complaining that Rpi4 is still using 32 bit stuff.  If that is true, then you have no luck.  Otherwise I will google more and learn some AOSP and try to play with it. (I am a huge fan of Android, using Galaxy C9 Pro). Cheers.

Comment: This post and other similar posts say Rpi is only 32 bit: https://www.quora.com/Can-a-Raspberry-Pi-3-run-a-64-bit-OS-or-is-it-limited-to-32-bit

Answer (score 1):

The documentation at https://source.android.com/setup/build/initializing actually does say something about the host architecture. The package names imply an x86_64 host that also supports i386 binaries via multiarch.

Some users have attempted to run the AOSP build flow natively on aarch64 systems<sup>[1]</sup>, but this is unfinished research.

A means to build AOSP on a Pi requiring not as much creativity would be to install `qemu-user-static` and develop inside a Debian x86_64 chroot. This can be done even from a 32-bit distribution such as Raspbian. Keep in mind, although you have said:

> I can live will long build times

the limited horsepower of the Pi 4 combined with an order of magnitude slowdown due to emulation may result in a build time of days to weeks.

The Pi 4 is marketed as a desktop replacement, not a development workstation replacement.

<sup>[1]</sup> [C/C++ Toolchain for Android Build on aarch64 (WIP)](https://jsteward.moe/toolchain-for-android.html)